# Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied - pyenv install 3.x.x on Windows 10

Tags: python, vbscript, windows-10, runtime-error, pyenv

I wanted to install a new `Python` version via [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win), but always get the error mentioned in the title.

The output for two different versions I tried is this (in `PowerShell`):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pyenv install 3.9.0
:: [Info] ::  Mirror: https://www.python.org/ftp/python
C:\Users\user\.pyenv\pyenv-win\libexec\pyenv-install.vbs(0, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pyenv install 3.8.0
:: [Info] ::  Mirror: https://www.python.org/ftp/python
:: [Downloading] ::  3.8.0 ...
:: [Downloading] ::  From https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/python-3.8.0-amd64-webinstall.exe
:: [Downloading] ::  To   C:\Users\user\.pyenv\pyenv-win\install_cache\python-3.8.0-amd64-webinstall.exe
:: [Installing] ::  3.8.0 ...
:: [Info] :: completed! 3.8.0
C:\Users\user\.pyenv\pyenv-win\libexec\pyenv-install.vbs(0, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied
```

Earlier, this was not a problem.
I even tried with started the `PowerShell` with admin-rights, still not working.

In addition, I've filed an [issue request](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/236) on the [GitHub-page of the project](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win).

Comment: You installed pyenv-win with same user?

Comment: Yes, in fact there is only one user on the computer (me). Or would it make a difference, say, if I installed pyenv-win with an explicit admin-PowerShell, or not?

Comment: can you follow the link and look the file permissions https://superuser.com/questions/364083/windows-list-files-and-their-permissions-access-in-command-line/364085 post the permission data if you still need help

Comment: You mean I should apply some permission upgrade to the specific folder `C:\Users\user\.pyenv\pyenv-win\libexec\pyenv-install.vbs(0, 1)`, or what do you suggest me to do concretely?

Comment: Note that the developer himself is working on a solution, see: https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/236#issuecomment-841863923